# Camunda Modeler no advance mode button

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I am looking through the documentation and trying to familiarize myself with the more advance features of the Camunda modeler and noticed in the dmn documentation that some screenshots have a button displaying called "Enter Advanced Mode":

[image]

but my modeler never shows it:

[image]

I tried tracking it down and downloading the latest version of the modeler but can't figure out why it isn't showing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the github repo for the Camunda Modeler it looks like this feature was removed during the update to a React based UI last November.  It looks like the screen shots are out of date.

It is no longer present after this commit from November of 2018.

https://github.com/camunda/camunda-modeler/commit/85765888b57b90ab048afed03550a4acbf981511